# If an element $c\in\mathbb{U}_m$ has order $o$, then $\mathbb{U}_m$ has elements of every order less than $o$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I’m trying to prove that, if some $c\in\mathbb{U}_m$ has order $o$ (i.e. $c^o = 1$), $\mathbb{U}_m$ contains elements of every order less than $o$. It seems to me that perhaps this has something to do with $\mathbb{U}_m$ being a cyclic group, however I’m not sure where to begin with this.

Edit: $\mathbb{U}_m$ is the set of units in $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Comment: If indeed $\mathbb U_m$ is a cyclic group, then the orders of its elements are all divisors of the order of the group.  That won't have the property that every natural number less than an order is an order, unless the order of the group is $2$.

Comment: Or if it has order n!

Comment: @Sorfosh: given the edit, your comment only applies if $m = n!+1$ is prime.

Comment: Why do you believe this to be true?

Comment: Since we are talking about groups where the orders of elements are consecutive integers, I thought about this. I managed to construct groups where the element orders are $1,2,\dots,n$ for $1\leq n\leq 7$ ($1$, $S_2$, $S_3$, $S_4$, $A_6$, $S_5$, $A_7$). A theorem of Brandl and Wujie from 1991 states that I only missed one out, $n=8$, where $\mathrm{PSL}_3(4).2$ is the example. They furthermore give a complete classification of such groups. So I learned something new.